# How to convert InstancedBufferGeometry to a normal BufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I use a `LineGeometry`, which is actually a `InstancedBufferGeometry`, to draw a random line.
and with `three-mesh-bvh` to detect its intersection with other meshs.

Now the problem is `three-mesh-bvh` seems to not support `InstancedBufferGeometry`,
is there a way to convert a `InstancedBufferGeometry` to a normal `BufferGeometry`

I've tried `mergeBufferGeometries`, but it's not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `InstancedBufferGeometry` inherits from `BufferGeometry`, so you can just use `BufferGoemtry.copy` to pull the information into the `BufferGeometry`.